# AWS Cloudwatch for ELB monitoring exclude a route

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

WE have AWS Cloudwatch alarm set to ELB-5XX. One of our API keeps causing it shoot beyond its limit. We have a marketing event coming up and we probably won't be able to fix the root cause of it beforehand.

I want to exclude this route from ELB-5XX alarm. Is this possible? Maybe through a modified query.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it is Application Load Balancer because this can be achieved very easily on ALB.

- Go to your ALB's target group, view and edit rules.
- Click on + -> insert rule
- Add condition by choosing path for example -> /admin
- add action, you can here forward to other target group or redirect to another host with 301 status code or return a fixed response code of your choice, of course, anything except 5xx response code otherwise it will add up to your cloudwatch alarm

[Docs for reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-update-rules.html)

Comment: I will check this.

Comment: if you found it useful, and if it works for you; acceptance would be appreciated as this can help others in the future